# "more" button on Careers 2.0 not working

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, jobs

On my Careers 2.0 profile I recently earned a "more" button beside the list of tags I have top 10% in. Only one tag is hidden in there, but I can't see it, and the `more...` link beside the tags that do show doesn't do anything. In fact when I inspect it it doesn't seem to have an event listener attached to it.

I am using Google Chrome version 13.0.782.107
Link to profile: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/pauloldridge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry about that Paul.  This should be fixed now.  Just a little hiccup in some javascript I deployed last night.  Thanks for the report!